# GAE quick to start nodejs service but 15 minutes to accept requests

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm running a nodejs12 standard service in GAE with these settings:

```
runtime: nodejs12
env: standard
service: default
instance_class: B1

env_variables:
  GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT: (hidden)
  GCLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET: (hidden)

basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1
  idle_timeout: 30m
```

For some reason my service takes up to 15-20 minutes to accept a request after starting up from idle. Not always, sometimes it's instant. The logs look the same for both cases, except the request log gives a "protoPayload.latency: 1,224.6 s" instead of the usual 5-10ms when it works as it should.

It's not related to my nodejs code I think, as it doesn't matter what I request, it doesn't seem to catch the request at all until after this delay. I can see the server starting up as it should in the logs.

Any idea what's wrong or how I can investigate this further?

Comment: What's your region?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere It's on europe-west6, should I try another region?

Comment: Hmm, yes, create a new project and try in another region, us-central1 for example. You accumulate 2 factors: Zurich region is quite new, nodeJS 12 is in beta. Maybe both generate unexpected result!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I tried nodeJS 10 instead, it was slow the first test after deploy, but the follow 5 tests were instant. But now it's slow again. It would be quite tedious to make a new project and move everything over, would you happen to have any more ideas I can try before going there?

Comment: You maybe can try to switch to automatic scaling and to see if it's the same thing. If so, try to set a min-instance to 1 and see if it occurs again. It's maybe a cold start issue/long init.